# foreach loop does not encode and insert all bitmaps into my sqlite DB

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, foreach, sqlconnection

**My code:**

```
private void BTN_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string DBpath = @"Data Source=.\StudentDB.db;Version=3;";
            Bitmap[] PictureBoxesBitmaps = { FirstPictureBitmap, SecondPictureBitmap, ThirdPictureBitmap };
            using SQLiteConnection connection = new(DBpath);
            using SQLiteCommand cmd = new(DBpath, connection);
            foreach (Bitmap bitmap in PictureBoxesBitmaps)
            {
                System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new();
                bitmap?.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
          
                    byte[] BitmapByteArray = ms.ToArray();
                    var PictureBox64  = Convert.ToBase64String(BitmapByteArray);
                    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO PictureBoxes(Encoded) VALUES('" + PictureBox64 + "')";
             
            }
            connection.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
}
```

Only the first bitmap is encoded and inserted into the database.

My intention is to encode all bitmaps present in the `PictureBoxexBitmaps` array then insert them into the database.

I tried putting `connection.Open();` `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` and `connection.Close();` under the foreach loop but that only encoded and inserted the first bitmap three times.

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: also: you're only _executing_ your query ***once*** because it's outside of the loop.

Comment: To move `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` INSIDE the loop would be a good idea.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann wow, there really is a xkcd for everything. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command is being run only once, To fix the issue you need to move the below line inside the loop.

```
connection.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
connection.Close();
```

and as a suggestion use `using` with the `SQLiteConnection` and please use the parameterized query to avoid SQL injection.

**Edit:**

As @madreflection suggested you could only move the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` inside the loop to avoid opening/closing the connection again and again. Thank you

Comment: Only `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` needs to be inside the loop. Opening and closing the connection on every iteration is costly and totally unnecessary.